# "Driven from" sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning

> These countries will have a vast number of experienced and productive
>   older workers who, as things stand, will be **driven from the workforce
>   upon reaching the age of sixty-five by the widespread practice of
>   requiring** workers to retire at that age.

I know all the vocabularies in the sentence, but having problem understanding the sentence as a whole (especially because of the bold part). Can someone explain what this sentence means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> driven from the workforce upon reaching the age of sixty-five

These people will no longer be able to work when they reach 65.

> by the widespread practice of requiring workers to retire at that age

A **practice** is a standard way of doing things

**requiring** means telling somebody that they must do something, for example retire when they reach 65.

**widespread** means that a lot of companies follow this practice.